# if else + loop + update values in a column vector

Tags: r, if-statement, vector

i have the following data.

```
X Hour Minute Second  Value
1 1    8     24     21 6898.4
2 2    8     24     22 6898.4
3 3    8     24     23 6898.4
4 4    8     24     24 6898.4
5 5    8     24     25 6898.4
6 6    8     24     26 6898.4
```

Now i want to record the average value of "Value" for observations when the value of the "Minute" variable stays same. For example, for the 24th minute, there are 30 observations, for the 25th minute, there could be 15 observations and so on.

I want to make a data frame which stores only the `Hours`, `Minutes`, and the average value of "Value" (over the seconds)

Comment: Try `aggregate(Value~Hour+Minute, df1, mean)` or `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(Hour, Minute) %>% summarise(Value=mean(Value))`

Comment: Hi Akrun, thanks for taking time out. but this won't help much because the entries in the minute and hour columns would repeat themselves as date changes. unfortunately date is not their in the data..

Comment: It may be helpful if you could create a slightly bigger example with all the conditions you mentioned and the expected result based on that.